# Paypal Direct Payment path errors

Tags: path, paypal

I'm using Paypal's Classic API to do Direct Payment on my site.

At the beginning of the DirectPayment sample on DoDirectPayment.php there is this line:

```
require_once('../PPBootStrap.php');
```

and it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PPAutoloader.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php') in /Users/jasonburton/Sites/georgetown/wp-content/themes/georgetown/paypal_direct_payment/samples/PPBootStrap.php on line 12
```

Now, that PPAutoloader.php call is an include within bootstrap. This doesn't just happen in bootstrap, it happens with all files that I try to include. The paths are just not right and I don't know what to do. I've echoed out my path in terminal and it just gives me:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Any hints on how I can fix this problem? I know I'm not giving much information here but it's all I've got at the moment.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run Composer ? We are using Composer for dependency management.

https://getcomposer.org/

Instructions are in the SDK Readme file too: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/master/README.md